# Hyperbolic Spirals (first time learning with ThinkPython)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, hyperbolic-function

I'm learning Python (for fun) through the book ThinkPython. So far I'm really enjoying this new hobby. One of the recent exercise was crafting a Archimedes spiral.In order to test my skills I've been working on making a hyperbolic spiral but have been stumped!

according to the equation *r=a+b*theta^(1/c)*

- when *c=1* we see a Archimedes spiral
- when *c=-1* we should see a hyperbolic spiral

I'm using the following code and would appreciate any help towards the right direction.

- Extra points to whoever can help me in the right direction without directly giving away the answer. Unless it's simply a formatting issue.
- No points if the answer suggested involves using (x,y) coordinates to draw.

```
import turtle
import math

def draw_spiral(t, n, length=3, a=0.1, b=0.0002):
    """Draws an Archimedian spiral starting at the origin.

    Args:
      n: how many line segments to draw
      length: how long each segment is
      a: how loose the initial spiral starts out (larger is looser)
      b: how loosly coiled the spiral is (larger is looser)

    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral
    """
    theta = 0.1

    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        dtheta = 1/((a + b * (theta**(1/-1))))

        t.lt(dtheta)
        theta += dtheta

# create the world and bob
bob = turtle.Turtle()
draw_spiral(bob, n=1000)

turtle.mainloop()

"""Source code from ThinkPython @ http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/code/spiral.py

edited to attempt a hyperbolic spiral"""
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adjusting the constants passed to `draw_spiral()` as arguments:

```
def draw_spiral(t, n, length=1, a=0.01, b=60):
```

I was able to generate a spiral along the lines you describe:

[image]

However, it draws from the *outside in*, not the *inside out*.  So, may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: yes! thank you for your response. outside in should be fine i'm only grading myself here :) haha, I def had a line that looked very similar to yours and went off screen. I assumed that I was making a mistake and it was failing to create it. There must be some way to zoom out my turtle display so I can see where the little guy goes. I'll look up how to do that and see if i was making one the whole time but outside my field of view.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer of @cdlane, it is just a matter of the arguments. I'll extend the answer.

For the [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) add the argument `c` to the function `draw_spiral`:

```py
def draw_spiral(t, n, length=3, a=0.1, b=0.0002, c=-1):

    theta = 0.1
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        dtheta = 1/((a + b * (theta**(1/c))))

        t.lt(dtheta)
        theta += dtheta
```

And use the following arguments, for instance:

```py
draw_spiral(bob, n=1000, length=1, a=0.01, b=0.001, c=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! I was able to successful craft a Archimedean spiral but was working on a hyperbolic Spiral. My impression was my formatting of the formula was wrong but It looks like the whole time I was creating one but it was outside my field of view. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.